# Tiles not rendering in SFML despite basically being a dressed up rectangle class

Tags: c++, sfml

```
class Tile : public sf::RectangleShape {

public:
    Tile(); 
    Tile(float);
    ~Tile();

    void highlightTile();
    bool isTileHighlighted() const;
    void turnOffHighlight();

private:
    sf::RectangleShape m_tile;
    bool m_isHighlighted;
};


Tile::Tile()
{
}

Tile::Tile(float squareDim) : m_tile(sf::Vector2f(squareDim, squareDim)), m_isHighlighted(false) {
}


bool Tile::isTileHighlighted() const {
    return (m_tile.getOutlineColor() == sf::Color::Yellow);
}

void Tile::turnOffHighlight(){
    m_tile.setOutlineThickness(0);
}

void Tile::highlightTile() {
    m_tile.setOutlineThickness(5);
    m_tile.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Yellow);
}

Tile::~Tile(){
}


Grid::Grid(float squareDim) 
{
    Tile tilePiece(squareDim);
    sf::Vector2f position(0, 0);
    int counter = 0; //counter for whether the column is even or odd
    int counter1 = 0; //counter for whether we are on an even or odd row
    for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
        for (int column = 0; column < 8; column++) {

            if (counter1 % 2 == 0 && counter % 2 == 0 || counter1 % 2 != 0 && counter % 2 != 0) {
                tilePiece.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
            }
            else {
                tilePiece.setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
            }

            tilePiece.setPosition(position);
            m_tileSet[row][column] = tilePiece; //correct coordinates
            m_gridMap[row][column] = sf::Vector2f(tilePiece.getPosition().x + squareDim / 2, tilePiece.getPosition().y + squareDim / 2);
            position.x += squareDim;
            counter++;
        }
        position.y += squareDim;
        position.x = 0;
        counter = 0;
        counter1++;
    }
}
```

The tiles are not rendering. I'm not sure the issue or whether I'm doing something wrong with the inheritance here and whether I should have the m_tile and that makes sense..

hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: I think you may benefit from inheriting `Tile` from `sf::RectangleShape` so you inherit functions like `setFillColor()` and you don't need a `getRect()` function. That way you can just focus on helper functions for setting/getting highlight state: `class Tile: public sf::RectangleShape {};`

Comment: great idea galik thanks, i fixed the tiles rendering originally but this actually reverted back the problem. Am i supposed to have sf::RectangleShape m_tile in the tile class still? Im not sure why its not rendering the tiles anymore....

Comment: By inheriting from `sf::RectangleShape` your `Tile` **becomes** a `sf::RectangleShape`, treat like one. You should not, then, also contain a separate shape with `m_tile`.

Comment: How would i rewrite these parts

m_tile(sf::Vector2f(squareDim, squareDim))


return (m_tile.getOutlineColor() == sf::Color::Yellow);


etc

Comment: nvm figured it out thanks Galik!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to draw `Tile` object (I suppose so, as you did not show us code which draws). But you never set its dimensions, that's why you can't see it. What you do is to set dimensions for member variable ( `m_tile(sf::Vector2f(squareDim, squareDim))` ) which is not used if you draw Tiles like this: `window.draw(tile)`.

You have to choose: either inherit publicly from RectangleShape or contain member object RectangleShape, not both.